# get feedburner feed on httpS

Tags: https, feedburner

We are grabbing our feed at feedburner by using the jquery jGFeed plugin.
this works great until the moment our users are on a httpS:// page.

When we try to load the feed on that page the user gets the message that there is mixed conteent, protected and unprotected on the page.

A solution would be to load the feed on https, but google doesn't allow that, the certificate isn't working.

```
$.jGFeed('httpS://feeds.feedburner.com/xxx')
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this. The way it functions now, we simply cannot server the feed in our pages when on httpS

Answer (score 1):

At this time Feedburner does not offer feeds over SSL (https scheme). The message that you're getting regarding mixed content is by design; in fact, **any and all** content that is not being loaded from a secured connection will trigger that message, so making sure that all content is loaded over SSL is really your only alternative to avoid that popup.

As I mentioned, Feedburner doesn't offer feeds over SSL, so realistically you'll need to look into porting your feed to another service that DOES offer feeds over SSL. Keep in mind what I said above, however, with respect to your feed's content as well. If you have any embedded content that is not delivered via SSL then that content will also trigger the popup that you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

This comes up from time to time with other services that don't have an SSL cert (Twitter's API is a bit of a mess that way too.)  Brian's comment is correct about the nature of the message, so you've got a few options:

1. If this is on your server, and the core data is on your server too, then you've got end to end SSL capabilities; just point jGFeed to the local RSS feed that FeedBurner's already importing.
2. Code up a proxy on your server to marshall the call to Feedburner and return the response over SSL.
3. Find another feed service that supports SSL, and either pass it the original feed or the Feedburner one.

Answer (score -2):

i have started using WordPress paid theme Schema for my several blogs. In general, it is a nice theme, fast and SEO friendly. However, since my blogs are all on **HTTPS**, then I noticed that if I had a widget of (Google Feedburner) in the sitebar. The chrome will show a security error for any secure page with an insecure form call on the page.

To fix this, it is really simple,

you would just need to change the file widget-subscribe.php located at **/wp-content/themes/schema/functions/** and replace all “**http://feedburner.google.com**” to “**https://feedburner.google.com**”.

Save the file, and clear the cache, then your browser will show a green padlock.

and i fix this in my this blog www.androidloud.com